# Using objective C++, can you create a property that is a C++ class and the getter returns a reference

Tags: objective-c++

I want to do this but have not seen it anywhere.

```
@property (nonatomic) MyCPPClass &myInstance;
```

I need it to write a getter that returns a reference and not a copy.

```
- (MyCPPClass &)myInstance {
      return _myInstance;
}
```

Or can it only be done with an iVar and writing my own getter and setter.

Comment: Are you sure that this needs C++ tag? AFAIK, there is no Objective C++, its just Objective C.

Comment: @razzorflame [Yes, there is Objective-C++.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041925/is-objective-c-a-totally-different-language-from-objective-c)

Comment: And to the original poster: Did you try it? What compile-time or run-time errors did you get?

Comment: @robmayoff what the what the??

Comment: What’s going to stop you here is that references can’t be NULL and the compiler has no guaranteeing that the ivar is intialised.

Comment: Removed tags C++ and Objective-C because they are different languages

Answer (score 0):

You may use a private instance variable for that:

```
@interface MyObjCPPClass

@property (nonatomic) MyCPPClass &myInstance;

@end

@implementation MyObjCPPClass {
    MyCPPClass _myInstance;
}

- (MyCPPClass &)myInstance {
    return _myInstance;
}

- (void)setMyInstance:(MyCPPClass &)instance {
    _myInstance = instance;
}

@end
```